# How to explain to young children what a web developer does

Tags: education

If you are a web developer parent, will you try to explain to your child your profession before he/she is old enough to understand computer science, e.g. via story-telling?

Or is it better to wait until he/she is old enough to teach them properly?

Comment: How young are we talking? What age do you consider "old enough to understand computer science"?

Comment: I am not very sure when children are old enough to be introduced to computer science properly, I am guessing 7+? Will any child be able to understand the actual process of web building before entering primary school???

Comment: I would keep it simple. Show her a webpage, and tell him that your job is building that page?

Comment: My friend is a web developer and his girls think he types in a text editor and prints out money

Answer (score 7):

As a web developer I put together a simple "Oregon Trail" style text game that would run on a basic web server and then had my kid play it.

Then as he was doing that I started adding thing (images, other responses, etc) and showed them how it changed as I added more logic and parameters.

It gave them a basic understanding of how development worked and how I could change things by changing the logic (e.g. changing the output of a random number from 50/50 odds to 60/40 odds to 80/20 odds).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how old was your child when you did this? (It's not the main question about, but OP seems interested based on the comments!)

Comment: Thank you! I am creating a children's story using visual metaphor to explain this topic, your answer has provided useful information for me.

Comment: Your answer sounds very intriguing also it sounds like a very good method.

Answer (score 2):

I explained as soon as my kids were capable of asking, which for them was around age 5.

The explanation at that age was very simple:  "I help put together web sites".  I think I used Youtube as an example of a web site.  I talked briefly about back end work versus front end work, since I do mostly back end work.  The answer seemed to satisfy them.

Comment: Thank you! I am creating a children's story using visual metaphor to explain this topic, your answer has provided useful information for me.

Answer (score 2):

When my child was 2, I made him a web page that ran only on our local machine.  He loved to press buttons.  When he ran the program, a big colored rectanglular mosaic would come up.  There was a random photograph of him layered under the colored rectangle.  Each time he pressed anything on the keyboard, a portion of the photo underlay would be revealed.  Once the photograph was complete, he could press a key to play the game again.

Another program I made for him: press a key, and a random photograph of himself appears.  Press a key, another photograph appears.

I told him I made the game.  That was the two-year-old explanation of web developer.